# Does a bounded sequence have a convergent subsequence in a Banach space?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is there any example of a bounded sequence in a Banach space that does not have a convergent subsequence?

Comment: The sequence of unit vectors in $\ell_p$, $1\le p\le\infty$. In fact, using [Riesz's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma), you can find such a sequence in any infinite dimensional normed space.

Answer (score 1):

> The sequence of unit vectors in $\ell_p$, $1\le p\le\infty$. In fact, using  [Riesz's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma), you can find such a sequence in any infinite dimensional normed space. -- [David Mitra](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/18986/david-mitra)